# How can I add custom sorting to commonNavigator in an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create an Eclipse plugin that contains a commonNavigator extension.

I can't figure out how to override the default alphabetical sorting. I want element type A to be before all the elements of type B. When I return the children of an element, I return them in the order that I want them, but they are displayed sorted.

I've seen a few really old tutorials that talk about a `customSorter`, but I am having trouble implementing it. [This tutorial](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/10/24/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-8-common-navigator-adding-a-new-sorter-under-navigatorcontent/) says to create it through `plugin.xml`, but when I try, I can only create a generic element, not a customSorter. I think it must be outdated because it didn't work even with the code that came with the tutorial.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you looking at the right menu? You must right click on the `navigatorContent` entry to get the menu with New / commonSorter.

Comment: I think so. I right clicked on both the org.eclipse.ui...navigatorContent as well as the actual name of the navigatorContent. Both new menus only offered me "generic"